# Сравнить разделенные запятой данные в базе с php массивом

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть поле, хранящее `id` категорий товаров, разделенные запятой
(не спрашивайте, почему... это, увы, поменять нельзя - да и поздно уже, база огромная).

Типа такого:

```
productID  categories  
---------  ------------
    13730  101,103     
    15336  101,109     
    15320  103,104     
    15310  104,105     
     1314  19,20       
      348  19,26       
     1309  20,21       
     4521  21,25       
     3739  29,68       
     4019  32,69
```

В `php` есть массив (например) `$categories = Array(20, 21, 101, 103);`.

**Задача**: надо найти все товары, у которых есть хотя бы одна категория из данного массива.

Можно перебрать все элементы массива по одному, что-то типа

```
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(20, table.categories)>0 OR 
FIND_IN_SET(21, table.categories)>0 OR 
FIND_IN_SET(101, table.categories)>0 OR 
FIND_IN_SET(103, table.categories)>0)
```

Но, боюсь, при большом массиве (а это вполне может случиться), запрос получится долгий: все-таки текстовая обработка идет, а не по целым числам, как хотелось бы...

Есть ли у кого какие-нибудь другие варианты?

Comment: Не только можно поменять, можно втупую сдублировать все данные в нормализованном виде, и искать уже там.

Comment: @Mike второй вариант - класс! То, что надо! Оформи как ответ, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соберите свой массив в php с помощью `implode('|',$categories`, после чего сформируйте SQL запрос в виде:

```
select * from table
 where table.categories regexp '(^|,)(20|21|101|103)(,|$)'
```

Но если вам надо искать очень быстро, категорий не особо много и категорий у одного продукта 2-3-4, то что бы не менять существующую систему, формирующую это поле категорий можно предложить следующее костылеориентированное решение:

1. Создаем таблицу "группы категорий", примерно такую (group_id,catlist varchar). Т.е. в ней будут лежать все встречавшиеся варианты набора категорий.
2. Заполняем таблицу с помощью `select distinct table.categories from table`
3. добавляем в таблицу `table` колонку `group_id`, строим по ней индекс, заполняем id групп из "групп категорий".
4. Создаем триггер на изменение поля `categories` у table, который во первых гарантирует, что перечисленные через запятую категории идут по возрастанию, во вторых при изменении поля он получает `group_id` для данного перечня категорий (возможно добавляя запись в таблицу групп) и заполняет то поле, что мы добавили
5. Создаем таблицу "категории в группах" вида (group_id,category_id). Т.е. в нее для записи в групах "103,104" кладутся 2 записи 103 и 104.
6. Делаем триггер на "группы категорий", заполняющий таблицу "категории в группах".
7. Строим индексы, поиск осуществляем прямо по id категорий в "категории в группах", по полученному `group_id` идем сразу в основную `table`
8. Возможно, делаем ежемесячную процедуру, удаляющую неиспользуемые группы.

Если у всех товаров по 3 категрии, 150 возможных категорий, то максимум возможно порядка 560k групп, при том, что вообще вариантов перестановок 150^3=3.3M. Это потому, что во первых не бывает повторяющихся цифр "1,1,1", во вторых мы отсортировали категории и вариантов "3,2,1" быть не может. В данном случае, для 150 категорий мы получили в 6 раз меньше возможных значений, чем максимум. C учетом того, что в жизни многие категории не сочетаемы, вариантов будет гораздо меньше и можно ожидать, что групп категорий будет 10%, а то и меньше, от кол-ва записей в основной таблице. Запрос вида `select count(1),count(distinct categories) from table` даст вам точный ответ каково это соотношение на ваших данных и сможете решить стоит ли игра свеч.

Answer (score 1):

Mike, спасибо большое - вы помогли решить задачу...
причем упростили предыдущее решение

```
WHERE field_cats REGEXP('^{$id_cat}|^{$id_cat}\\\.|^\\\.{$id_cat}$|\\\.{$id_cat}\\\.|\\\.{$id_cat}$')
```

Это если один `айди` надо было найти, например `айди` юзера какого-то, или категории
но вот также понадобилось выводить несколько чекбоксов-параметров, зависящих от категории..
(То есть, в параметрах есть поле с `айдишками` категорий 1.5.3.4
А при заходе в категорию отбираются все подкатегории, с вложениями.
То есть массив их айдишек...
И надо найти совпадения и вывести только те параметры, которые соответствуют своим категориям, с их вложениями)

И вот код

```
WHERE field_cats REGEXP('(^|.)($id_cat)(.|$)')
```

просто элегантно выполняет поставленную задачу.

Причем, как говорил, упрощает код, даже когда одну айдишку надо найти (уже не приходится 4 возможных варианта вносить в `regexp`)...

надеюсь, не преждевременно радуюсь )))) ибо пока работает как бы как надо.

СПСБ.