# Правильный SQL запрос для сложных данных

Tags: mysql

У меня в таблице есть столбец, который содержит строку типа 1,2,3,4,5 (то бишь implode обычного массива в php). Столбец называется mett
Нужно каким-то образом выбрать только те записи, в которых есть хотя бы 1 элемент из заданного массива. Например если в таблице 1,2,3 а в массиве входных данных 2 4 6, то нужно вывести эту строку, т.к. число 2 есть в массиве.
Как это сделать? Как разбить строку в массив, потом просмотреть есть ли элемент массива в заданном массиве?
Нужно сформировать правильный select запрос. Типа select * from table where mett in ('1','2','3')

Comment: Перекроить БД. Представлять отдельные элементы массива в виде строк в отдельной таблице, указывающих на строку в первой. Классический случай нормализации.

Comment: Насколько мне известны различные ситуации, такое допустимо лишь для хранения "materialized path" при реализации деревьев на реляциях или при простом хранении неопределенных заранее данных. И то, лучше материализованный путь сделать бинарным полем, или преобразовать в отдельную реляцию. При хранении такого содержимого в одном поле для возможности сопоставления с помощью `LIKE` (учитывайте, что любые индексы тут пролетают), лучше использовать формат типа `|1|2|3|4|5|`. При всем этом, в случае с деревьями такой индекс работает, поскольку сопоставление начинается с первого символа.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov никакой разницы в формате хранения нет. как вы будете like искать скажем 2. вы все равно напишите что то вроде `like '%|2|%'` и о индексе можно будет забыть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сравнить разделенные запятой данные в базе с php массивом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480682/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d1%81-php-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: @Mike спасибо, да, это решение

Comment: @D-side исключено, в базе очень много данных, заморачиваться нет ни времени, ни финансов

Comment: @AliVeliyev есть опасность, что дальнейшее существование этого костыля приведет к ещё большим временнЫм и финансовым потерям. Вам, конечно, лучше знать, но недооценивать эту проблему опасно.

Comment: @D-side я понимаю, спасибо! Там вообще вся база не из нормальной формы, так что лишний раз перестраивать всё это дело займёт уйму времени. Качество работы пропорциональна её оплате.

Answer (score 1):

Массив для сравнения нужно преобразовать в набор записей. Т.е. список

> в массиве входных данных 2 4 6

конвертируется в запросе в код, формирующий из этих данных таблицу:

```
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 6
```

Эта таблица будет вместе с исходной источником данных запроса.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table.*
FROM table
   , (
        SELECT 2 x UNION ALL
        SELECT 4   UNION ALL
        SELECT 6
     ) x
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(x.x, table.mett)
```

Но **в любом случае это плохое решение**. Настоятельно рекомендую прислушаться к совету **D-side** и нормализовать данные.

Comment: Большое спасибо, решение найдено в предложенном посте. Я бы мог нормализовать их если бы хотел, но у клиента слишком уж низкий бюджет для этого.